# Adding an entry to the table and page using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I study javascript. Got to ajax requests. Everything works fine in mvc. I decided to try on web forms. Trying to post a new entry on the page, please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code. The page code acts as the main view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Tables.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Tables" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table id="tab" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1408</td>
                    <td>Stiven King</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txbName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txbAuthor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txbPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Добавить" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<script>
    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Tables.aspx/AddBook",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "Name": $('#txbName').val(),
                "Author": $('#txbAuthor').val(),
                "Price": $('#txbPrice').val()
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (MyDT) {
                $('#tab tbody').append(MyDT);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.statusCode)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Web method code, controller:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string AddBook(string Name, string Author, int Price)
        {
            db = new Context();
            string html = "";
            Book book = new Book() { Name = Name, Author = Author, Price = Price };
            db.Books.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();

            html = GetHTMLRow(book);
            return html;
        }
```

And another method of obtaining html code for further adding an entry to the page, something like a partial view on which the entry is going to:

```
public static string GetHTMLRow(Book book)
        {

            string htmlRow = $"<tr><td>{book.Name}</td><td>{book.Author}</td><td>{book.Price}</td></tr>";
            return htmlRow;
        }
```

My code is completely working, but for some reason the page is restarted. But shouldn't ajax request work asynchronously without touching the page? In MVC everything works fine. And then why not? What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you click the button it submits the form(because the type is set to "submit"). change it to "button"

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Добавить" />
```

Comment: Pandurang, thanks. The form no longer reloads, but for some reason the addition of a line to the page does not work. `success: function (MyDT) {
                $('#tab tbody').append(MyDT);`, but if I myself execute this code on the client itself a line is added, why is that so?

Comment: do a `console.log(MyDT)` and see if you are getting expected results. I see a `$` sign in your `$html_row` string. so remove it and try `string htmlRow = "<tr><td>{book.Name}</td><td>{book.Author}</td><td>{book.Price}</td></tr>";` may be that is the cause.

Comment: Pandurang, MyDT contatin `d: "<tr><td>sdfsf</td><td>dsfsdf</td><td>23424</td></tr>"`maybe because of this? What you see is interpolation of strings in c #.

Comment: I tried to do it like this, but the result is the same. `string htmlRow = "<tr><td>" + book.Name + "</td><td>" + book.Author + "</td><td>" + book.Price + "</td></tr>";`

Comment: I have a feeling that the fact is that besides the html code in MyDT, there is a d:

Comment: Pandurang, I figured it out. `success: function (MyDT) {
                $('#tab tbody').append(MyDT.d);`

Comment: it looks like d, it is an element object

Comment: Great. happy to help.